# Why does my laptop think my battery is dead?

Tags: 11.04, laptop, power-management, battery

I've got about a 3 or 4 hour battery life on my laptop. I've had Ubuntu 11.04 on it for a week or so now, and yesterday, it started telling my I had a critically low battery (.3%), and suspends. When I plug it in and unplug it a few times, it stops complaining, and runs for hours. Is there a way I could fix this, or even just tell Ubuntu to ignore a critically low battery?

Comment: Did it happen again? I had a similar experience. There was a momentary power surge that only lasted a couple of seconds but Ubuntu kept saying the battery was critically low, even while it was still plugged (was so worried it fried my laptop or battery). I unplugged from AC and rebooted. This somehow reflected the true remaining battery (which was full). Had to drain the batter all the way down to critically low level before I plugged it again. This somewhat fixed it.

Comment: It's happened a few times since yesterday, but I usually keep my battery pretty topped off. I'll try draining it and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Ubuntu to ignore it by opening `gconf-editor`, then go to `/apps/gnome-power.manager/actions/critical_battery` and change it to `nothing`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to let your laptop battery drain all the way (you might need to turn off the auto-suspend) and then letting it charge all the way up, all while running Ubuntu. It's often hard to know a battery's "empty" and "full" states without having some kind of measurement, and if this calibration is way off, then the percentage will be way off as well.